# Map does not appear upon opening print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

When I open my print project in print composer, my map is not there upon opening. There is only a little note that says "your map will print here".

What is going on here?
[image: Print composer screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the refresh button it should appear if you didn't modify the extent or removed the layers:

Also, you need to change the `Rectangle` to `Render` to see the content.

[image]