# Map is not shown in Print Composer or in PDF (QGIS 2.18.3)

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2.18

I already saw the other questions concerning the same problem, but after trying everything described in the answers there, I still have the problem that my saved print compositions do not show the maps. Not only do they not show in the print composer but also in the printed PDF version there's only white.

As I work with bigger compositions with many maps in one file, it would be great if there is a way to "repair" these.

It was mentioned in [Map does not appear upon opening print composer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241345) that this could happen, if you delete or modify the map layer -
 because it didn't work properly I had to remove my basemap content .

Could this be the reason for this problem and if so, is there a way to repair it?

Comment: what is your basemap content? and how did you add it?

Comment: I use a WMTS Layer of Austria (https://www.basemap.at/).

Comment: Just checking, so when you open your map/data in print composer it is completely blank? No basemapping or data? I have had problems with WMS showing when exporting to a PDF, but this was due to the resolution being too high... But I don't think this is your problem?

Comment: Apart from the map everything shows in the print composer (text, pictures, frames etc.) it's just the map content (I still see the rectangle from the map).

Comment: And no, I don't think it's because of the resolution being too high...It seems like the print composer just doesn't recognize the map or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a solution for the problem I encountered with the question I asked, BUT I think I at least found the reason why my map didn't show in the print composer:

before printing the PDF, I had to change the coordinate system / projection of my project (it was wrong before) and apparently the print composer didn't recognise my map anymore. I tried changing it back just for printing, but that didn't change anything and it still was not printing my map. So, I still don't know the reason for my problem, but know now, how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens rather often to me, so the issue has obviously not been fixed. My way around the problem is to reduce a little on the resolution. If this does not help, I close down the project and restart Qgis. That normally solves the problem - but it´s still annoying:)